# R DocumentTermMatrix control list not working, silently ignores unknown parameters

Tags: r, matrix, controls, tm

I have two following DTM-s:

```
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(t)

dtmImproved <- DocumentTermMatrix(t, 
               control=list(minWordLength = 4, minDocFreq=5))
```

When I implement this, I see two equal DTM-s and if I open the `dtmImproved`, there are words with 3 symbols. Why doesn't the `minWordLength` parameter work? Thank you!

```
> dtm
A document-term matrix (591 documents, 10533 terms)

Non-/sparse entries: 43058/6181945
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 135 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
> dtmImproved
A document-term matrix (591 documents, 10533 terms)

Non-/sparse entries: 43058/6181945
Sparsity           : 99%
Maximal term length: 135 
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

Comment: Moreover, when I add anything into "list (...)" nothing happens, no warnings or sth else

Answer (score 25):

```
dtmImproved <- DocumentTermMatrix(t, control=list(wordLengths=c(4, 15), 
                                   bounds = list(global = c(5,Inf))))
```

This solves the problem! The lack of proper documentation really mads me down (:

Comment: Which version of `tm` are you using. The help for `TermDocumentMatrix` sets out the global options and gives a link to the local options. `minWordLength` is never listed as an option, but `wordLengths` is described in detail. The documentation appears well written and easy to follow.

Comment: Yep, that was the one that helped, unfortunately couldn't find by googling, but it's more like my fault )

Comment: @mnel : it silently ignores any parameter it doesn't recognize, even e.g. `(control=list( bounds=list(c(0,Inf))) )` instead of `(control=list( bounds=list(global=c(0,Inf))) )`. This is a big pain. Did you spot the missing label 'global'? I didn't...

Answer (score 0):

It is always a good idea to read the source code if available. Read the Source code of the wordcloud function@GitHub, here is what it says:
    # Author: ianfellows
    .....
    if(min.freq > max(freq))
    min.freq <- 0

So your DocumentTermMatrix, returned a max(freq) < min.freq bound that you set, i.e. non-of the terms appeared in more than  your min.freq bound that you set.

Hope this Helps
MJJ