# Trying to remove words from a DocumentTermMatrix in order to use topicmodels

Tags: r, tm, topic-modeling

So, I am trying to use the `topicmodels` package for `R` (100 topics on a corpus of ~6400 documents, which are each ~1000 words). The process runs and then dies, I think because it is running out of memory.

So I try to shrink the size of the document term matrix that the `lda()` function takes as input; I figure I can do that do using the `minDocFreq` function when I generate my document term matrices. But when I use it, it doesn't seem to make any difference. Here is some code:

Here is the relevant bit of code:

```
> corpus <- Corpus(DirSource('./chunks/'),fileEncoding='utf-8')
> dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
> dim(dtm)
[1] 6423 4163
# So, I assume this next command will make my document term matrix smaller, i.e.
# fewer columns. I've chosen a larger number, 100, to illustrate the point.
> smaller <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=list(minDocFreq=100))
> dim(smaller)
[1]  6423 41613
```

Same dimensions, and same number of columns (that is, same number of terms).

Any sense what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer to your question is over here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13370840/1036500 (give it an upvote!)

In brief, more recent versions of the `tm` package do not include `minDocFreq` but instead use `bounds`, for example, your

```
smaller <- DocumentTermMatrix(corpus, control=list(minDocFreq=100))
```

should now be

```
require(tm)
data("crude")

smaller <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control=list(bounds = list(global = c(5,Inf))))
dim(smaller) # after Terms that appear in <5 documents are discarded
[1] 20 67
smaller <- DocumentTermMatrix(crude, control=list(bounds = list(global = c(10,Inf))))
dim(smaller) # after Terms that appear in <10 documents are discarded
[1] 20 17
```