# Text mining with R package tm- idf for Large Corpus - cannot find common words

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

So, I am analyzing a huge corpus. It has about 40,000 documents in it. I am trying to analyze it using R's  tm package. I created a document term matrix that reads 100% Sparsity, meaning that there are no common words in this corpus.

```
library(qdap)
library(SnowballC)
library(dplyr)
library(tm)

docs <-Corpus((DirSource(cname)))

docs <-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(tolower))
docs <-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(removeNumbers))
docs <-tm_map(docs,content_transformer(removePunctuation))
docs <-tm_map(docs,removeWords,stopwords("english"))
#docs<- tm_map(docs, stemDocument)
dtm <- DocumentTermMatrix(docs)

<<DocumentTermMatrix (documents: 39373, terms: 108065)>>
Non-/sparse entries: 2981619/4251861626
Sparsity           : 100%
Maximal term length: 93
Weighting          : term frequency (tf)
```

I removed all of the infrequent words and I got this:

```
dtms <- removeSparseTerms(dtm, 0.1)
dim(dtms)
[1] 39373     0
```

Is R acting this way because my corpus is too big?

**Update**

So I have been doing quite a bit of searching on this issue. This seems to be a parallel computing problem. I'm not really sure. But I have stumbled upon these hand outs that talk about distributed text mining in r [Link](http://www.rinfinance.com/agenda/2010/Theussl+Feinerer+Hornik.pdf)

**More Updates***

So I guess my question was a duplicate question I found the answer in various places. One was in the [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/c/job-salary-prediction/forums/t/4076/large-scale-text-mining-in-r/33781) website for data science competitions. The other two answers are here at stackoverflow
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16287546/trying-to-remove-words-from-a-documenttermmatrix-in-order-to-use-topicmodels) and another [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13366897/r-documenttermmatrix-control-list-not-working/13370840#13370840). I hope this helps. Also there is great examples of the tm package on the [hands on data science site](http://handsondatascience.com/TextMiningO.pdf) and great documentation of text processing in R at [gaston's](http://gastonsanchez.com/Handling_and_Processing_Strings_in_R.pdf) page as well.

Comment: What exactly is unexpected here? What were you trying to do with `removeSparseTerms`? If there are no overlapping terms in documents, each term would have a sparsity of 1/39373 which is much smaller than 0.1 so you're removing them all.

Comment: @MrFlick forgive because I a completely new to the world of text mining.  I did not expect the corpus to be 100% sparsity. I was expect terms with frequency of age|1.97657922 agglomeration|2.57863921 aggregates|2.57863921.

Comment: How certain are you that there are overlapping terms in your documents? Are you sure you are creating your corpus correctly? You haven't exactly created a reproducible problem here so we have no idea what's in your data.

Comment: @MrFlick You maybe right. I think I might be using the wrong package. I am checking out the [slam package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/slam/slam.pdf) that deals with these sort of problems

Comment: Can you tell me the total number of words in the corpus? There are 108k unique terms, the total number of words should give a fair estimate of the sparsity.

Comment: @jackStinger I am not able to tell you the total number of words in the corpus. I get an error because of the sparsity. I've been doing some more digging into the problem and it seems like this is a parallel computing problem. Unfortunately my teacher failed to teach us anything about hadoop or hive.

Comment: Where and how is your data stored? And, how large is your data?

Comment: @jackStinger My data is 151 MB and its on my laptop.

Comment: you shouldn't ideally need parallel computing for 151 mb of data- I've worked with far larger numbers in-memory in R. Is it possible to share the data- I can take a look at it.

Comment: Can you run rowsum(as.matrix(dtm)) on your dtm and plot the histogram?

Comment: @jackStinger here is a link to my  data [Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l9ea74zkkn8pct3/clean1%20%281%29.zip?dl=0)

Comment: @jackStinger I fear the only way to do this is with python.

Comment: @jackStinger so like I almost cracked it. I will put up an updated post right now

Comment: `removeSparseTerms(..., 0.1)` is applying a (pretty large) 10% threshold(!), not a 0.1% threshold. Reduce the threshold until you get a non-empty output, then tell us what threshold value that was.